# Timer to schedule a task

Tags: java, android, timer, bluetooth, handler

I need to check continously a variable's value. This is a value that I receive from the bluetooth's input stream, this is the reasson why I need to this be continuosly checking it.

What I need to do too, is that when i call the function, it returns to me the value saved in the variable in that moment.

For that, I'm doing this:

```
private final Handler refresh_handler = new Handler();

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Runnable refresh_input = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            bt_read_input = GlobalVar.bt_input;  //Save received value in a local variable
            refresh_handler.postDelayed(refresh_input, 500);
        }
    };
}

refresh_handler.post(refresh_input);  //Call to the function
```

This seems to be refreshing the variable every 0,5sec. But I still need that when I call it, it returns to me the actual variable's value, this is, `bt_read_input`'s value in that moment.

How could I implement a function to do this as a timer, but also to return the variable's value to get it when I want?

Comment: How could I implement a function to do this as a timer, but also to return the variable's value to get it when I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieved this in a very simple way:

```
private final Runnable refresh_input = new Runnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    bt_read_input = GlobalVar.bt_input;
    }
    refresh_handler.postDelayed(refresh_input, 250);
}
```

};

This way I'm refreshing the variable's value every 250ms and when I want to use the value of it, I just havo to call to `bt_read_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

**1) create an interface say BloothListener.java**

```
public interface BloothListener {
        void onReadValue(String value);
    }
```

**2) Create Function say startListing**

```
public void startListing(final BloothListener bloothListener){

        final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        try{
            final Timer t = new Timer();
            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final String bt_read_input = GlobalVar.bt_input;
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            bloothListener.onReadValue(bt_read_input);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 0, 500);
        }catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }
```

**3) How to use from your activity onCreate() method**

```
startListing(new BloothListener() {

            @Override
            public void onReadValue(String value) {
                // get your value and use it

            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok, I've created a new class called BloothListener.java and copied there 1) and 2). But after each closing `}` appears an error telling me to delete the token. So, maybe  I'm copying it wrong way? Have I to add something more?

Comment: its a syntax error dude that how could I know how you pasted it?

Comment: I copied it as you put it here. First the 1) and after it the 2) in the BloothListener.java

Comment: Had you put 1) and 2) in activity declaration part where you declare the variables?

Comment: I'm not sure about what do you mean. I've just created a new interface and copied there the 1) and 2) snipets as you posted here. So, there is something more that I have to do then?

Comment: can you come to chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37096/discussion-between-biraj-zalavadia-and-masmic-87)

Comment: Excuse me @Biraj Zalavadia, I'm waiting for you in the chat. Could you help me with this please?